# offset answer for a simpledateformat parsing

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have the following code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);
String timeStr = "10:00 PM";
Date timeDat;
try{
    timeDat = sdfHour.parse(timeStr);
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    return;
}
int hour = timeDat.getHours();
int minute = timeDat.getMinutes();
```

And the resulting values are

hour=>22  and   minute=>30

No matter what time I use, it always adds 30 minutes.
I read several posts, but I still could get a clear answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: above code working correctly. check again.

Comment: I´m using the android phone emulator. The clock inside the virtual phone shows the same time offset (30 minutes) in relation to the computer clock where I´m working. I guess that is the source of the offset, but I don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: i can't understand what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**I executed your code in my system and its giving perfect output:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class DateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);
        String timeStr = "10:00 PM";
        Date timeDat;
        try{
            timeDat = sdfHour.parse(timeStr);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            return;
        }
        int hour = timeDat.getHours();
        int minute = timeDat.getMinutes();
        System.out.println("hour :"+hour+":: Min  "+minute);
    }
}
```

I am not able to see any problem here mate

**OUTPUT:**

```
hour :22:: Min  0
```